# unable to add Facebook SDK in iphone application

Tags: iphone, facebook, youtube-api

I am working on an iphone application where i am uploading video to youtube i have successfuly worked around that.

Now when i try to integarte the facebook in app it is creating a problem due to SBJason.h file in both the sdk. as both the sdk have SBJason file in their SDK kit.

So i need to have any workaround you can suggest.

Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove one of the SDK's `SBJson`.

First see which is the updated one

If you see any updated one, keep it and remove the older one.

If Both are same, so you can remove any of them, it will not effect the project (hopefully)